# how to persist data in @post endpoint

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

When i package this code, deploy and try to enable on jboss i see the following error.

```
Fri Jun 15 16:29:42 GMT+200 2018
Failed to enable master-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war.
Unexpected HTTP response: 500

Request
{
    "address" => [("deployment" => "master-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")],
    "operation" => "deploy"
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"master-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#master\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"master-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#master\": java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;II)V
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;II)V"}},
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

[image: bean]
[image: enpoint]
[image: model]
[image: persistence]
[[image: structure][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS18a.png)

Comment: do you state hibernate as provided in your pom.xml?

Comment: What libs do you put into your war ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, I discover that scope of my org.hibernate packages in pom file was provided so the libs were not copied into libs folder.